# Logging camera access on OS X Yosemite and up

Tags: camera, macos

I'd like to have camera access by applications be logged in system logs, so that I can later search for camera access in the console app. Any idea if there is some debug feature in OS X to enable logging ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain how you would do it natively, but by pure coincidence I discovered this today, from Obdev, the makers of Little Snitch.

> **[Micro Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html)**
>
> Ever wondered if an application records audio through your Mac’s built-in microphone without your knowledge? Or if the camera captures video for no good reason?
>
> With Micro Snitch there’s no doubt anymore. This ultra-light menu bar application operates inconspicuously in the background. It monitors and reports any microphone and camera activity to help you figure out if someone’s spying on you.
>
> **Logging**
>
> Never miss any microphone or camera activity, even in your absence. Every status change is logged to a file, so you can review it later to find suspicious activities.

€3.99 direct, or also on Mac [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/micro-snitch/id972028355?ls=1&mt=12&ct=odweb) showing at $3.99 US or £2.99 UK

*No affiliation, & I haven't tried it myself; I'm just a satisfied user of Little Snitch.*